# Saving game state

Tags: java

I'm making a typing only game(no graphics) in which I need to save the state of the game and reload later. I've been thinking but could think of nothing(I'm not a very experienced programmer). Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: start for java basis, then try to do a minesweeper on console, then figure out how to save the state of the minesweeper

Comment: A simple solution would be to write your data to a file, so that it persists over time. There are plenty of examples of this everywhere.

Comment: have you considered serialization? http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaSerialization/article.html

Comment: Depending on what you actually need to _persist_, you could create a simple text file with whatever state you want to save and read the file back to restore the state

Comment: You should use serialization to store all objects state and then use deserialization to load them back.
Here is a nice tutorial to start from:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: try java Serializable , you can save/load any object with this .

Comment: Please re-write the question with a _specific_ example of what you want to save and reload later and give **examples** of what you have tried already. SO is not a code shop.

Comment: @FlameKnight123 Put them into an `ArrayList` and write the `ArrayList` to a file. That does not change the fact that you need to implement `Serializable` yourself

Comment: Basically most of above comments point you to the right direction. I would like to add that object that you create should be serializable, you can read about creating serializable objects at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Answer (score 3):

You need your class to implement `Serializable` interface. Then write the object to a file. Then on start up read the file back again.

> To serialize an object means to convert its state to a byte stream so
>   that the byte stream can be reverted back into a copy of the object. A
>   Java object is serializable if its class or any of its superclasses
>   implements either the java.io.Serializable interface or its
>   subinterface, java.io.Externalizable. Deserialization is the process
>   of converting the serialized form of an object back into a copy of the
>   object.

The beauty of `Serialzable` interface is that you do not need to implement any methods. It is a marking interface. You just make a class `Serializable` and then write it out to a file.

Word of caution here: You need to truncate the file every time you write to it. Do not try to append data to it. It corrupts the header of the file.

Tutorials here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ObjectOutputStream` and call its method `writeObject` to save your game state.

And use `ObjectInputStream` and call its method `readObject` to load game states.

e.g.

**Save Game state**

```
public void saveGameDataToFile(File file) {   

    try {   
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);   
        ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);   

        objectStream.writeObject(flag);   
        objectStream.writeObject(color);   
        objectStream.writeObject(snake);   
        objectStream.writeObject(food);   
        objectStream.writeObject(new Integer(score));   

        objectStream.writeObject(barrier);   
        objectStream.writeObject(new Boolean(needToGenerateFood));   
        objectStream.writeObject(new Boolean(needToGenerateBarrie));   

        objectStream.close();   
        fileStream.close();   

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, 
            "Save game state successfully.", 
            "Snake Game",   
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);   
    } catch (Exception e) {   
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, 
            e.toString() + "\nFail to save game state.",   
            "Snake Game", 
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);   
    }   
}
```

**Load Game state**

```
public void loadGameDataFromFile(File file) throws ClassNotFoundException{   

    ... ...

    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);   
    ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileStream);   

    svaedFlag = (int[][]) objectStream.readObject();
    savedColor = (Color[][]) objectStream.readObject();     
    savedSnake = (Snake) objectStream.readObject();   
    savedFood = (Grid) objectStream.readObject();   
    savedScore = (Integer) objectStream.readObject();   
    savedBarriers =(Barriers) objectStream.readObject();   
    savedNeedToGenerateFood = (Boolean)objectStream.readObject();   
    savedNeedToGenerateBarrie = (Boolean)objectStream.readObject();   
    ... ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for persisting the Object state you can

1. use serialization
2. safe the contents to file  as text or xml
3. save the contents to database (sqlLite,hsql)

Comment: I think point 3 should be moved to point 0 ?? :P .. Serialization first, then dumping...

Comment: @X86 updated Serialization first, as many people prefered that