# Looking for enhanced algorithms : Save game state

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, savestate, autosave

I used to [serialize objects states and save them to a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784628/saving-game-state) (or XML file) to load later however I have no idea how some games preserve game state in any time without heavy saving actions or a background scheduled auto save. I used `File.WriteAllBytes` and `File.ReadAllBytes` in **C#** + **unity3d** and I have similar experience using Java [serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) but both of them are time consuming and need some seconds to write data into file or database.

In some City Management Games, any time I close the game it is closed instantly and there is no boring saving and no background process after closing as I have in a simple game. There are too many characters in the game and I have noticed they are loaded later by all minor details as well as an incomplete laugh voice! I wonder how this amount of data is being saved instantly in any time?

Are there enhanced algorithms to keep live state of too many characters at every time?

Comment: From the bits and pieces of experience I have, I suggest it is done by doing all the hard work, including using an optimized proprietary binary format and avoiding memory allocation during saving as much as possible, as well as small optimizations such as opening the file handle in advance and keeping it.

Comment: XML and databases are very inefficient for storing and loading game state on the fly. Binary serialization is the way to go. Aside from that, there is no reason not to offload this kind of work to a background thread and use the async versions of the methods you mentioned. Along with what user @Zyl mentioned, storing game state really doesnt **have** to be slow at all if you are smart about what data you save, and how (and when) you save it.

Answer (score 1):

In unity you can use scriptable objects. Just store each saveable thing the moment it happens. This way you dont have any exit time.